# mavenizing liferay compliant JVM 1.6 error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, liferay

I'm following [This guide](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/installing-required-liferay-artifacts) for mavenizing my liferay. I followed it step by step. When I ran *ant clean start jar* command as said in stage 5, I got an error saying **Annotation processing got disabled, since it requires a 1.6 compliant JVM** and a much bunch of errors following. I changed my default java and javac to 1.6.0_45 by **sudo update-alternatives --config java** and **sudo update-alternatives --config javac**
. After that I ran again and got the same errors. What can I do to get rid of this error?

Note: I used to have this problem in eclipse but I solved it by setting my project compaliance level to 1.6.

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the language level in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I'm sorry for my noobines, but how can I do that? According to the mentioned tutorial I did not set any pom.xml and I wonder if the liferray source has any pom.xml to be configured!

Comment: Setting compiler level with properties: ....https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html